# How to upgrade friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer?

Tags: magento2, php-7

Server: CentOS 7
PHP: 7.3.13
Litespeed: Enabled
Magento: 2.3.3

I was attempting to run some updates via composer when I received an error about my PHP being too high.

[image]

I attempted to upgrade php-cs-fixer from v2.13.3 to v2.16.1 (which supports PHP73) - however, this failed for the same message as below (under Problem 1). Server was downgraded to PHP7.2 but when running the command

```
composer update friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer
```

I received a message that there was nothing to update??

I ran the following command to see if it was a composer error

```
composer diagnose
```

which pointed out I was running composer 1.8.9 (which has now been updated to 1.9.1).

Any idea how I can upgrade php-cs-fixer to allow me to run composer commands on PHP7.3

Comment: You should check this with Mageplaza or use the Magento packaging.

Comment: The example is with mageplaze - but all composer updates don't seem to work when on php7.3.

I compared my composer.json and composer.lock files to those off a fresh Magento 2.3.3 download and they differ vastely.

Comment: If I create copies of my servers composer.lock and composer.json, and override them with the downloaded magento 2.3.3 zip then I get errors of the following
,,,
- magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework 2.3.14 requires php 7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0|~7.2.0 -> your PHP version (7.3.13) does not satisfy that requirement.
,,,

Comment: Problem Solved: I copied over the composer.json and composer.lock from the Magento-CE-2.3.3-2019-09-26-03-30-45.zip and then ran composer update (seems to have updated a lot of modules).

Answer (score 0):

Change this line from your composer.json

"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.13.0"

to:

"friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.16.0"

Answer (score 0):

You can run following command

```
composer require --dev friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer=^2.14 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

It should update the php-cs-fixer version which supports Php7.3 version.